# Sorting Multidimensional array several levels

Tags: php, arrays

I am currently trying to sort a multidimensional array by its `totalPoints`. Each array `lineupSet` has an `n` amount of items. I am trying to get the `lineupSet` with the the highest total `totalPoints`. How could I achieve most efficiently? the below is sudocode and therefore not working. Unsure how to approach this.

Code

```
public function getHighestTotalPoints($testArray)
{
    if (isset($testArray) && !empty($testArray)) {
        uasort($testArray, function ($a, $b) {
            return $a['lineupSet']['formula']['totalPoints'] <=> $b['lineupSet']['formula']['totalPoints'] ;
        });
        return array_reverse($testArray);
    }
    return null;
}

$testArray = [[
    "lineupSet" => [
        [[
            "formula" => [
                "totalPoints" => 214.61,
            ],
            "name"    => "test1",
        ], [
            "formula" => [
                "totalPoints" => 201.17,
            ],
            "name"    => "test2",
        ]], [
            "formula" => [
                "totalPoints" => 5.01,
            ],
            "name"    => "test3",
        ]],
], [
    "lineupSet" => [
        [[
            "formula" => [
                "totalPoints" => 220.66,
            ],
            "name"    => "test1",
        ], [
            "formula" => [
                "totalPoints" => 214.76,
            ],
            "name"    => "test2",
        ]],
    ],
], [
    "lineupSet" => [
        [[
            "formula" => [
                "totalPoints" => 205.71,
            ],
            "name"    => "test1",
        ], [
            "formula" => [
                "totalPoints" => 204.43,
            ],
            "name"    => "test2",
        ]],
    ],
], [
    "lineupSet" => [
        [[
            "formula" => [
                "totalPoints" => 205.48,
            ],
            "name"    => "test1",
        ], [
            "formula" => [
                "totalPoints" => 203.51,
            ],
            "name"    => "test2",
        ]],
    ],
]];
```

Desired result:

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [lineupSet] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [formula] => Array
                                    (
                                        [totalPoints] => 220.66
                                    )

                                [name] => test1
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [formula] => Array
                                    (
                                        [totalPoints] => 214.76
                                    )

                                [name] => test2
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

Comment: Is `totalPoints` the *only* element in the `formula` array?

Comment: @Nick hi, great question. So at times there could be more elements then `totalPoints` in `formula`

Comment: I get a syntax error. One too many `[` somewhere

Comment: @Ibu there's one too many `],` at the end of the first `lineupSet`

Comment: @Ibu sorry, made the correction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`usort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to sort the array according to a custom function. This function determines the `totalPoints` for a given `lineupSet`:

```
function sum_points($v) {
    $totalPoints = 0;
    foreach ($v['lineupSet'] as $lset) {
        if (isset($lset['formula'])) {
            $totalPoints += $lset['formula']['totalPoints'];
        }
        else {
            foreach ($lset as $l) {
                $totalPoints += $l['formula']['totalPoints'];
            }
        }
    }
    return $totalPoints;
}
```

To sort descending (so the maximum total points is in the first entry of the array), we then use a sort function which returns a positive number when the second value's `totalPoints` are bigger than the first, a negative number when it's smaller and 0 when they are the same:

```
function sort_points($a, $b) {
    return sum_points($b) - sum_points($a);
}
```

Finally we call `usort` with this function and output the first element of the array:

```
usort($testArray, 'sort_points');
print_r($testArray[0]);
```

Output:

```
Array (
    [lineupSet] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [formula] => Array
                                (
                                    [totalPoints] => 220.66
                                )

                            [name] => test1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [formula] => Array
                                (
                                    [totalPoints] => 214.76
                                )

                            [name] => test2
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/oIOoD)

Comment: could I please use your help here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55720393/custom-sorting-multidimensional-with-n-items-by-highest-value