# Custom sorting multidimensional with n items by highest value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am currently able to sort a multidimensional array using a custom sorting method. Each array `lineupSet` has an `n` amount of items. The function `sort_points` will sort each `lineupSet` from highest to lowest `totalPoints` and then it will give me the `lineupSet` with the the highest total `totalPoints`. I am currently changing the approach, I still want to sort through each `lineupSet` first and order highest to lowest. Then I would like to get the highest `totalPoints` of each `lineupSet` based on a given count. What would be the best way to approach this?

Test Array:

```
$testArray = [[
    "lineupSet" => [
        [[
            "formula" => [
                "totalPoints" => 214.61,
            ],
            "name"    => "arr0-test0",
        ], [
            "formula" => [
                "totalPoints" => 201.17,
            ],
            "name"    => "arr0-test1",
        ]], [
            "formula" => [
                "totalPoints" => 5.01,
            ],
            "name"    => "arr0-test2",
        ]],
], [
    "lineupSet" => [
        [[
            "formula" => [
                "totalPoints" => 214.76,
            ],
            "name"    => "arr1-test0",
        ], [
            "formula" => [
                "totalPoints" => 220.66,
            ],
            "name"    => "arr1-test1",
        ]],
    ],
], [
    "lineupSet" => [
        [[
            "formula" => [
                "totalPoints" => 205.71,
            ],
            "name"    => "arr2-test0",
        ], [
            "formula" => [
                "totalPoints" => 204.43,
            ],
            "name"    => "arr2-test1",
        ]],
    ],
], [
    "lineupSet" => [
        [[
            "formula" => [
                "totalPoints" => 205.48,
            ],
            "name"    => "arr3-test0",
        ], [
            "formula" => [
                "totalPoints" => 203.51,
            ],
            "name"    => "arr3-test1",
        ]],
    ],
]];
```

Sorting Function

```
function sum_points($v) {
    $totalPoints = 0;
    foreach ($v['lineupSet'] as $lset) {
        if (isset($lset['formula'])) {
            $totalPoints += $lset['formula']['totalPoints'];
        }
        else {
            foreach ($lset as $l) {
                $totalPoints += $l['formula']['totalPoints'];
            }
        }
    }
    return $totalPoints;
}

function sort_points($a, $b) {
    return sum_points($b) - sum_points($a);
}

usort($testArray, 'sort_points');
print_r($testArray[0]);
```

For example I want to get the top two highest 'totalPoints'. The desired outcome:

```
Array (
    [lineupSet] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [formula] => Array
                                (
                                    [totalPoints] => 220.66
                                )

                            [name] => arr1-test1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [formula] => Array
                                (
                                    [totalPoints] => 214.76
                                )

                            [name] => arr0-test0
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I want to do the same for the top `n` highest `totalPoints`. Keeping in mind that it will have to take at times `n` items from each `lineupSet` that are the highest `totalPoints`.

Comment: You're doing a lot more than sorting, you're reducing. For that reason, I'd reach for array_reduce. Could also approach this as two separate sorting operations, the inner arrays and the outer array.

Comment: @Ultimater that’s a good point. I haven't worked with `array_reduce` before. could you show me how to apply those approaches to this?

Comment: Should the second entry actually be 214.76 (`totalPoints` from the second entry in the highest sorted `lineupSet`)?

Comment: @Nick, you are correct. I copied pasted that incorrectly.

Comment: I think you need to loop on every array and on every subarray to get the total result of every array

Comment: The one problem I'm not sure about is what would happen if you were to just consider the first element and the separate element was `"totalPoints" => 205.01` which means it's value is in between the other two.  How should this appear?

Comment: I undid Maxim's edit to the question. He corrupted the input data that was originally given to us and made it incompatible with the desired results.

Comment: @MaryCoding Is there any particular reason your first lineupSet looks like this? `[["arr0-test0", "arr0-test1"],"arr0-test2"]` rather than this? `["arr0-test0", "arr0-test1","arr0-test2"]` Is that a typo or can there be unlimited dimensions to these lineup structures?

Comment: @MaryCoding Based on your sum_points function's logic, it looks like you're allowing an optional extra dimension. How will this affect your top `n` sorting logic if you have an extra dimension to deal with? Would you be flattening it, or preserving the extra dimension in your desired results if such an array were the top?

Answer (score 5):

I think it's better to use an object then you can keep max while you are sorting data  (also you can use a constructor to sort the array).

```
Class SortHelper{
    public $max = 0;

    private function checkMax($totalPoints){
        if($totalPoints > $this->max)
            $this->max = $totalPoints;
    }

    private function sum_points($v) {
        $totalPoints = 0;
        foreach ($v['lineupSet'] as $lset) {
            if (isset($lset['formula'])) {
                $totalPoints += $lset['formula']['totalPoints'];
                $this->checkMax($lset['formula']['totalPoints']);
            }
            else {
                foreach ($lset as $l) {
                    $totalPoints += $l['formula']['totalPoints'];
                    $this->checkMax($l['formula']['totalPoints']);
                }
            }
        }
        return $totalPoints;
    }

    private function sort_points($a, $b) {
        return $this->sum_points($b) - $this->sum_points($a);
    }

    public function sort($array){
        usort( $array, [$this, 'sort_points']); 
        return $array;
    }
}
```

then you would have:

```
$sortHelper = new SortHelper();
$sorted_array = $sortHelper->sort($testArray);

var_dump($sorted_array[0]);
var_dump($sortHelper->max);
```

Comment: This looks like a nice approach that gets the OP closer to a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out,

```
$n = 2; // number of elements 

$testArray = [[
    "lineupSet" => [
        [[
            "formula" => [
                "totalPoints" => 214.61,
            ],
            "name"    => "arr0-test0",
        ], [
            "formula" => [
                "totalPoints" => 201.17,
            ],
            "name"    => "arr0-test1",
        ]], [
            "formula" => [
                "totalPoints" => 5.01,
            ],
            "name"    => "arr0-test2",
        ]
    ],
], [
    "lineupSet" => [
        [[
            "formula" => [
                "totalPoints" => 214.76,
            ],
            "name"    => "arr1-test0",
        ], [
            "formula" => [
                "totalPoints" => 220.66,
            ],
            "name"    => "arr1-test1",
        ]],
    ],
], [
    "lineupSet" => [
        [[
            "formula" => [
                "totalPoints" => 205.71,
            ],
            "name"    => "arr2-test0",
        ], [
            "formula" => [
                "totalPoints" => 204.43,
            ],
            "name"    => "arr2-test1",
        ]],
    ],
], [
    "lineupSet" => [
        [[
            "formula" => [
                "totalPoints" => 205.48,
            ],
            "name"    => "arr3-test0",
        ], [
            "formula" => [
                "totalPoints" => 203.51,
            ],
            "name"    => "arr3-test1",
        ]],
    ],
]];

function sort_points($a, $b)
{
    return ($a['formula']['totalPoints'] > $b['formula']['totalPoints']) ? -1 : 1;
}

$result = [];

$reference = &$result['lineupSet'][0]; // store reference in $reference

foreach ($testArray as $tA) {
    foreach ($tA['lineupSet'] as $t) {
        foreach ($t as $child) {
            $reference[] = $child;
        }
    }
}

usort($reference, 'sort_points');
$reference = array_slice($reference, 0, $n);
var_dump($result); // desired output
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this 2 functions, the steps as follows:

1. `sort_points();` Sort it with arsort PHP function and return it to new simplified array.
2. `transform_arrays($sortedArray, $testArray);` $testArray will be changed the value by the sortedArray.
3. copy all the codes into single file of `.php` and run it.

*i assume that we don't care about the complexity, also in real life (in this case my life) there is nothing such the case that you need to sort in multidimensional array, because array is just the storage to keep the data can be read by human.

---

```
<?php

$testArray = 
    [
        ['lineupSet' => [[['formula' => ['totalPoints' => 214.61],'name' => 'arr0-test0'],['formula' => ['totalPoints' => 220.66],'name' => 'arr1-test1']]]],
        ['lineupSet' => [[['formula' => ['totalPoints' => 205.71],'name' => 'arr2-test0'],['formula' => ['totalPoints' => 204.43],'name' => 'arr2-test1']]]],
        ['lineupSet' => [[['formula' => ['totalPoints' => 205.48],'name' => 'arr3-test0'],['formula' => ['totalPoints' => 203.51],'name' => 'arr3-test1']]]]
    ];

// sort into another array
function sort_points($testArray = []){
    $response = $result = [];
    $i = 0;
    foreach($testArray as $array2){
        foreach($array2['lineupSet'][0] as $item){
           $result[$item['name']] = $item['formula']['totalPoints'];
           $i++;
        }
    }
    arsort($result);

    $i = 0;
    foreach($result as $key => $val){
        $response[$i]['name'] = $key;
        $response[$i]['totalPoints'] = $val;
        $i++;
    }
    return $response;
}

// this won't work if the $testArray format structure is changed
function transform_arrays($items, $testArray){

    $l = 0;
    for($i=0;$i<count($testArray);$i++){
        for($j=0;$j<count($testArray[$i]);$j++){
            for($k=0;$k<count($testArray[$i]['lineupSet'][$j]);$k++){
                $testArray[$i]['lineupSet'][$j][$k]['formula']['totalPoints'] = $items[$l]['totalPoints'];
                $testArray[$i]['lineupSet'][$j][$k]['name'] = $items[$l]['name'];
                // print_r($testArray[$i]['lineupSet'][$j][$k]['formula']['totalPoints']);
                // print_r($testArray[$i]['lineupSet'][$j][$k]);
                $l++;
            }

        }
    }
    return $testArray;
}

echo '<pre>';
$sortedArray = sort_points($testArray);
$response = transform_arrays($sortedArray, $testArray);
print_r($response);
echo '</pre>';
```